# Linux partition in two different physical disks

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, filesystem

I'd like to create a manual partition for my Linux Xubuntu using two different phisical disks.
I'd like to put Boot, Swap and / in a SSD Disk and use a traditional cylinder disk for /home

Is it possible?
Is it easy?

Thanks

Roberto Zavadlav

Comment: It is possible and very easy. But why would you need a separate `/boot` partition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Hi, thank for the answer... well, i'd like to put Boot, Swap and Root in a ssd because is speeder  and i prefer put /home in a traditional disk because people told me that ssd doesn't like a lot of write process and the /home directory is a place in which always i write, change, delete files.... but i'm not very expert. I accept suggestions

Comment: What you were told about SSDs was valid many years ago. Now, an SSD from a quality manufacturer will likely outlast HDDs, especially since TRIM is included in Ubuntu now.. Read https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ssd-storage-longevity-for-archival-not-write-endurance.3454065/   and https://insights.samsung.com/2019/02/11/why-is-ssd-better-than-hdd/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0  outlines and illustrates the installation process. When you get to step 6, [Allocate Disk Space,](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5)  choose Something Else. There, you can create a partition for /home on your HDD and put everything else on the SSD.

Please note there's no need for a separate Swap Partition in Ubuntu, and there hasn't been since 2017. Just let Ubuntu put swapspace in /home which it does automatically.

Now, that may not be necessary: What you were told about SSDs was valid many years ago. Now, an SSD from a quality manufacturer will likely outlast HDDs, especially since TRIM is included in Ubuntu now.. Read https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ssd-storage-longevity-for-archival-not-write-endurance.3454065/ and http://insights.samsung.com/2019/02/11/why-is-ssd-better-than-hdd for an intriduction to the modern SSD.